# Admin email value stuck in database?

Tags: email

I recently changed the admin email in a WordPress instance. When a user leaves a comment on a post, there is no email notification sent. I have turned off and back on the option to email when a someone leaves a comment. This results in an error in the email provider's log (the site is using Postmark) that shows the comment notification is being sent to the old email address (which Postmark is then not delivering for other reasons).

Note: All other notifications (administrative notifications, contact form notifications) are successfully being delivered to the new email address. Only comment notifications are attempting to deliver to the old email address.

My guess is that a value didn't get updated in the database somewhere, but not sure where to look. Can someone advise?

Thanks!